# PostGIS - find vertices on polygons without partners

Tags: postgis, proximity, vertices

My goal is to ensure that a set of boundaries have vertices that are co-incident where they intersect by a tolerance of 5m. So I am looking for orphan vertices that are not on an external boundary.

I constructed the following query:-

```sql
WITH POINTS_DUMP AS (
    SELECT (ST_DUMPPOINTS(ST_COLLECT(wkb_geometry))).* 
    FROM boundary_table
), NO_PROXIMITY_POINTS AS (

    SELECT distinct on (A.path)
           A.geom,
        count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY A.path)
    FROM POINTS_DUMP A
    LEFT JOIN POINTS_DUMP B
    ON ST_DWITHIN(A.geom::GEOGRAPHY,B.geom::GEOGRAPHY, 5,TRUE) 
    AND A.path != B.path


)
SELECT row_number() OVER () as fid,
       geom AS wkb_geometry
FROM NO_PROXIMITY_POINTS
WHERE count = 1
```

I believe this should give me the external boundary points (I will remove those later and any point on a boundary internally that is more than 5 metres from another point.

However, this is giving me all internal points and not the external boundary points. Surely if the count is "1" then the point must be an orphan?

What am I doing wrong?